# My text value is getting empty every time in React

Tags: reactjs, web-chat, react-ref

This is my code here I am trying to get the value of input of the webchat using refs.
In the below code `const message` is always empty and in the stop function the focus doesn't focus as soon as I click stop.

I am using azure speech.

```
**Edit:** 
const WebChatRef = React.createRef();

function App() {

const currentWebchat = WebChatRef.current as HTMLDivElement | null;
  const textBox = currentWebchat?.querySelector(
    ".webchat__send-box-text-box__input"
  ) as any;
  const textBoxRef = useRef(null);
  textBoxRef.current = textBox;

**Initial Code:** 

const [recognizing, setRecognizing] = useState(false);
  const [recognizer, setRecognizer] = useState<SpeechRecognizer | undefined>(
    undefined
  );
  // const [val, setVal] = useState("")

  const textBoxHandler = (e: React.KeyboardEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    if (e.key === 'Enter') {
  //@ts-ignore
  const message = textBox?.value.trim();
        console.log('message at enter', message);

      if (message) {
        empwc.sendMessage(message);
      }
    }
    console.log("e", e);
  };

  const startButton = () => {
    if (textBox) {
      textBox.removeEventListener("keyup", textBoxHandler as any);
      textBox.addEventListener("keyup", textBoxHandler as any);
    }
    if (recognizing) {
      stop();
      setRecognizing(false);
    } else {
      setRecognizing(true);
      if(textBox) {
        textBox.value = "";
      }
      console.log("record");

      const audioConfig = AudioConfig.fromDefaultMicrophoneInput();

      const speechConfig = SpeechConfig.fromSubscription(
        SUBCRIPTION_KEY,
        SPEECH_REGION
      );
      speechConfig.speechRecognitionLanguage = "en-US";
      speechConfig.enableDictation();

      const recognizer = new SpeechRecognizer(speechConfig, audioConfig);
      recognizer.recognizing = recognizerCallback;
      recognizer.recognized = recognizerCallback;

      setRecognizer(recognizer);
      recognizer.startContinuousRecognitionAsync();
    }
  };

  const recognizerCallback = (s: any, e: any) => {
    const speechText = e.result.text;
    const reasonIndex = e.result.reason;
    console.log("e.result", e.result);

    if (speechText) {
      switch (reasonIndex) {
        case ResultReason.RecognizedSpeech:
          textBox.value += speechText;
          console.log('value',textBox.value)
          break;
        default:
          break;
      }
    }
  };

  const stop = () => {
    if (recognizer) {
      recognizer.stopContinuousRecognitionAsync(
        () => {
          recognizer.close();
          setRecognizer(undefined);
          if (textBoxRef.current) {
            textBox.focus();
          }
          console.log("stopped");
        },

        (err: any) => {
          console.error(err);
        }
      );
    }
  };
}
```

HTML code

```
<div
                className=""
                id="webchat"
                ref={WebChatRef as React.RefObject<HTMLDivElement>}
                style={{ display: tab === "home" ? "block" : "none" }}
                role="main"
              >
```

Everything is fine but when I try to get the value of textbox on WebchatRef, everytime I get empty value.

Edit: attaching a photo of rendered Input text field of webchat on DOM

[image]

Comment: Where is `textBox` being set?  I don't see it.

Comment: you don;t see coz its rendered on the DOM, in the HTML the ref shows a webchat in the browser and that's where everything renders. Added the image

Comment: But somewhere, someone has to have a Javascript statement that says `textbox = ...` in order to make it accessible.  I don't see that.

Comment: My bad.. I did not add that piece of code. let me edit it one more time.